# MPMoviePlayerViewController crashing app in iOS 10 Xcode 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, ios10

Using xcode 8 and running on the ios10 simulator.  When trying to use MPMoviePlayerViewController, it will immediately cause my sample application to crash in the simulator. No exception or error is shown in Xcode so not sure how to debug this or what is the problem.

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *moviePlayer;
moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] init];
```

The above code is enough to crash my app in ios 10 simulator.  The app closes immediately and nothing show in xcode.  No problems at all on the ios 9 simulator.

What can cause this and is there anything to do to debug the crash?

Comment: I am getting the same problem as you and the Apple docs say ' "Important
The MPMoviePlayerViewController class is formally deprecated in iOS 9. (The MPMoviePlayerController class is also formally deprecated.) To play video content in iOS 9 and later, instead use the AVPictureInPictureController or AVPlayerViewController class from the AVKit framework, or the WKWebView class from WebKit." I am trying a few other things now.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok I found the solution,

you have to let the user know what your media player is going to access,

1. Go to the info.plst and add the key NSAppleMusicUsageDescription - string
2. add some text (just for testing purposes)
3. run your app. A dialogue box pops up asking for access to the users media. Hit ok and it should run.

I used your code and ran it this way without a crash.

I hope that works.

Comment: Thank you so much, this fixed it!  This was driving me crazy.

Comment: Hi there... It does not work for me :/… Does anyone has an idea about what can possibly happen there?? I have added the "Privacy - Music Usage Description" and "Privacy - Media Library Usage Description" keys in the info.plist - But it does not pop the authorization dialog, and still crashes at first MPMoviePlayer usage..

Comment: Did you add text to the  NSAppleMusicUsageDescription key? Just add this key NSAppleMusicUsageDescription .